# VBA Text Compare

Tags: excel, vba

I'm relatively new to VBA and I'm trying to write a macro that will compare two columns of data (first and last names). While traversing the column, any time first name = last name (ie. they're both blank or say UNKNOWN) I want the cell in the 9th column to be cleared and the cell in the 10th column to get the value UNKNOWN.

As of now, the code correctly recognizes any time when the first and last name are identical. My problem is that any time first name is a sub-string of any last name (ie. cell I2=David J2=Jones , I3=Joseph J3=Davidson) David gets compared with Davidson and is subsequently erased.

I've spent a while looking for similar problems and I haven't been able to adapt anything to my problem thus far. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
 Sub compare_cols()

Dim Report As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer

Set Report = Excel.ActiveSheet

lastRow = Report.UsedRange.Rows.count 

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For i = 1 To lastRow ' This will find all identical pairs of cells in I,J (blank, blank) or (unknown, unknown). I stays blank, J gets UNKNOWN
    For j = 1 To lastRow    ' I think its currently erasing any matches (ex. if someones first name is James, it will get erased if there is a last name jameson)
            If InStr(1, Report.Cells(j, 10).Value, Report.Cells(i, 9).Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                Report.Cells(i, 9).Value = ""
                Report.Cells(i, 10).Value = "UNKNOWN"
                Exit For
            Else
            End If
    Next j
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike some other languages, you can compare strings in vba just using the "=" sign and that will find exact matches, which is what it appears you are looking for. Try

```
if Report.Cells(j, 10) = Report.Cells(i, 9) etc.
```

Comment: I exchanged my If statement for yours and now substrings are no longer deleted. However, any first and last names that are an identical match are still deleted. Any idea how to make cell I2 only compare with cell J2 and not all of column J? @Matt Cremeens

Comment: Then just use one loop and one loop variable. That will ensure that you are just comparing the same row for each column all the way down.

Comment: I removed the inner for loop and the "exit for" and it now works! thanks for the help @Matt Cremeens